# How to find intersection for two streams with java 8?

Tags: java, csv, enums, java-8, java-stream

I have following `csv` file:

```
OF_DEPARTURE_COORDINATE_Y,OF_ARRIVAL_COUNTRY,OF_ARRLV2,OF_ARRLV1,OF_ARRLV0,OF_ARRIVAL_CITY,OF_ARRIVAL_ZIPCODE,OF_ARRIVAL_COORDINATE_X,OF_ARRIVAL_COORDINATE_Y,OF_WEIGHT,OF_VOLUME,OF_LENGTH,OF_GOODS_KND,OF_TAIL_LIFT,OF_PALLETS_EXCHANGE,OF_NB_PALLETS
D,SN,1,,DRESDEN,01067,1372931,5105325,A,3,SB,57,ZELL AM SEE,5700,1279591,4732422,2500,0,36,MG,N,N,0
D,HE,35,,HAIGER,35708,820051,5074357,RO,2,,,ORADEA,410000,2193891,4705371,100,1,0,MG,N,N,0
F,NP,62,,ANVIN,62134,225617,5044640,F,BR,29,,QUIMPER,29000,-410790,4799464,10000,0,50,MG,N,N,0
```

I need to check how many times arrival and departure countries are mentioned there. And use for this functional approach. **CSV** file has only country codes. All countries are stored at predefined enum.

My solution works iteratively definitely, I am sure that it can be implemented with streams. I tried to play with `collect()` & `groupingBy()` but without success.

Here is iterative solution (result is stored to map with country for key - number of occurrences of values):

```
public class CountryCounter {
    private static Map<Country, Long> countryMap = Country.getCountryMap();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        processPath(FileLocation.SEARCHES_REG);
        printMap();
    }

    private static void printMap() {
        Map<Country, Long> reversedMap = new TreeMap<>(countryMap);
        Map<Country, Long> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        reversedMap.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.<Country, Long>comparingByValue().reversed())
                .forEachOrdered(x -> result.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));

        for (Map.Entry entry : result.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ", " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    private static void processPath(FileLocation filePath) {
        FileLocation.printFileName(filePath);

        Path path = Paths.get(".", filePath.getFilePath());

        List<String> csvLines = null;
        try {
            csvLines = Files.readAllLines(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (String csvLine : csvLines) {
            String[] lineArgs = csvLine.split(",");
            String arrivalCntCode = lineArgs[0];
            String departureCntCode = lineArgs[8];

            if (arrivalCntCode == null || departureCntCode == null) {
                return;
            }

            Country arrCountry = Country.getByCode(arrivalCntCode);
            Country depCountry = Country.getByCode(departureCntCode);

            if (countryMap.containsKey(arrCountry)) {
                countryMap.put(arrCountry, countryMap.get(arrCountry) + 1);
            }
            if (countryMap.containsKey(depCountry)) {
                countryMap.put(depCountry, countryMap.get(depCountry) + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`FileLocation` is enum for storing relative pathes for csv files.

Here you can find [Country enum](https://github.com/nazar-art/Java8ForReallyImpatient/blob/master/src/main/java/com/demo/ts/country/Country.java)

It works fine:

```
France, 82109
Germany, 31589
Romania, 27634
Italy, 11652
Netherlands, 9190
...
```

***How to achieve the same with `Java 8` features, like streams?***

Comment: I think you'd be much better served with a [MultiSet](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multiset), streams aside. What do you hope to gain, aside from the obvious [Files.lines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-) instead of `Files.readAllLines`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can:

- Use [`Files.lines(path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) instead of `readAllLines` to
  directly get the lines as a stream.
- Use [`flatMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to turn the lines into a stream of countries.
- Group the countries counting occurrences using a [downstream collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-).

For example:

```
public Map<Country, Long> count(Path path) throws IOException {
    return Files.lines(path)
            .flatMap(line -> getRelevantCells(line))
            .map(Country::getByCode)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
}

private Stream<String> getRelevantCells(String line) {
    String[] cells = line.split(",");
    return Stream.of(cells[0], cells[8]);
}
```

Comment: You solution should work fine. However, I tried it and got another result than from iterative approach. Can understand why does this happen.